# Theme is not displaying category products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, theme, template

I have a problem with my theme, the only thing i need is to display category products (products from one category, just one to be exact) and i really can't make it work.

This should work, because i found it with google and it worked for someone:

```
<p>{{block type="catalog/category_view" template="catalog/category/view.phtml" category_id="7"}}</p>
```

But it's not working for me, for some reason my theme doesn't seem to be working like this and I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php on line 44
```

changing the "block" to "widget" (it seems this theme works with widgets)

```
<p>{{widget type="catalog/category_view" template="catalog/category/view.phtml" category_id="7"}}</p>
```

removes the error but doesn't show anything.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Hello Jongosi, i'm using Magento 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to display those products from specific category on CMS Page?

If yes then use XML for this. Edit your Layout Update XML section while editing in CMS > Pages > Your page

```
<reference name="content">     
<block type="catalog/product_specials"  name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">   
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">         
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/></block>         
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>7</category_id></action>        
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>     
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to reach right category id - 7, do you have products inside of it? What's happening? Are some errors displaying? Check your /var/log/ files. If anything related please copy and paste it here.

Comment: Are you using Live environment or some local/testing? If the second one, you can enable logging errors in your installation so it will create logs in that directory. To turn on the logging, you can navigate to System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and set the «Enabled» option to «Yes»

Don't forget to set full access permissions (777) to the following folder: /var/log, that's the directory where those log files are saved. I wouldn't recommend to do that on live environment.